# How to Check monotonicity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

Given a function, $f$ be defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x=0 \\ \frac1{2^{n-1}} & \frac1{2^n}\lt x\le\frac1{2^{n-1}}, n\in\Bbb N\end{cases}$$

If I take $n =1$, then
$f(x) = 1$ and $\frac{1}{2} \lt x \le 1$

If $n =2$,  $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2^{2}} \lt x \le \frac{1}{2}$

If $n=3$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{2^{3}} \lt x \le \frac{1}{2^{2}}$

How should I find if the function is monotonically  increasing or decreasing? Really don't know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x\in (2^{-m},2^{1-m}], y\in (2^{-n},2^{1-n}]$ for positive integers $m,n$ with $m\leq n$. Then $x\geq y$ and

$$f(x)=2^{1-m}=2^{1-n}2^{n-m}\geq 2^{1-n}=f(y),$$

so $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Also note $f(0)<f(x)$ for $x>0$

Comment: Thankyou @Golden_Ratio

Comment: @YK16182 no prob